# How to make a shortcut for moving between Vim windows?

Tags: vim, window, buffer

Let’s say I have single Vim tab displaying 9 buffers (equally separated, like a 3×3 table).

Currently, to get from the top left window to the bottom right one, I have to press <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, and then <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>. This is cumbersome, and I would like to just be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to go to the 9th window, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to go to the 3rd window, etc.

Is there any easy way I can map something like this in Vim?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's a *much simpler* solution than using the mouse or hard-set movement mappings; they will break if the window numberings are different from what you have in mind for a 3x3 matrix, or if you decide to work with less than 9 windows. Here's how:

Include the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
let i = 1
while i <= 9
    execute 'nnoremap <Leader>' . i . ' :' . i . 'wincmd w<CR>'
    let i = i + 1
endwhile
```

Now you can just press `<Leader><number>` and be taken to the window number you want. I wouldn't recommend going beyond 9, because IMO, the utility of having multiple viewports follows a [Rayleigh distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) and quickly becomes useless with too many viewports in one window.

It will be helpful if you have the window number displayed in your `statusline` to aid you in quickly figuring out which window you're on and which window you want to go to. To do that, use this little function and add it accordingly in your `statusline`.

```
function! WindowNumber()
    let str=tabpagewinnr(tabpagenr())
    return str
endfunction
```

See it in action in your `statusline`:

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=win:%{WindowNumber()}
```

Note that the above line will replace your `statusline`. It was just meant for illustration purposes, to show how to call the function. You should place it where ever you think is appropriate in your `statusline`. Here's what mine looks like:

[image]

---

#### Update

[romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) asked for my status line in the comments, so here it is:

```
"statusline
hi StatusLine term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=White ctermbg=235
hi StatusHostname term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=107 ctermbg=235 guifg=#799d6a
hi StatusGitBranch term=bold cterm=bold ctermfg=215 ctermbg=235 guifg=#ffb964

function! MyGitBranchStyle()
    let branch = GitBranch()
    if branch == ''
        let branchStyle = ''
    else
        let branchStyle = 'git:' . branch
    end
    return branchStyle
endfunction

function! WindowNumber()
    let str=tabpagewinnr(tabpagenr())
    return str
endfunction

set laststatus=2
set statusline=%#StatusLine#%F%h%m%r\ %h%w%y\ col:%c\ lin:%l\,%L\ buf:%n\ win:%{WindowNumber()}\ reg:%{v:register}\ %#StatusGitBranch#%{MyGitBranchStyle()}\ \%=%#StatusLine#%{strftime(\"%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M\")}\ %#StatusHostname#%{hostname()}
```

The last line should be a single line (be careful if your setup automatically breaks it into multiple lines). I know there are ways to keep it organized with incremental string joins in each step, but I'm too lazy to change it. :) The `GitBranch()` function (with other git capabilities) is provided by the [git.vim plugin](https://github.com/motemen/git-vim). There's a bug in it as noted [here](http://www.osnews.com/story/21556/Using_Git_with_Vim) and I use the [fork with the bug fix](https://github.com/amjith/git-vim). However, I'm leaving both links and the blog here to give credit to all.

Also, note that I use a dark background, so you might have to change the colours around a bit if you are using a light scheme (and also to suit your tastes).

Comment: @yoda, I know we are not on the monthly screenshot thread of the Arch forum, but… would you mind sharing your statusline?

Comment: @yoda, the following goes to the 3rd screen `nnoremap <c-a> :3wincmd w<CR>` However, <c-3> does not work `nnoremap <c-3> :3wincmd w<CR>`  So for some reason the numbers are not working, any clue how to fix this?

Comment: @Kamilski81: I did fiddle with using `ctrl` briefly yesterday and I couldn't get it to work either, which is why I gave the solution using `<Leader>`. I thought I had made some silly mistake when trying with `ctrl` but since you get the error too, perhaps I'll look at it when I get some free time. BTW, I have my `<Leader>` set to `" "` (or space bar), so it's actually really easy to hit space and a number than ctrl+number...

Answer (score 10):

**Better, more general answer:**

Use *count*<kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd> to jump to the *count* window below/right of the current one.

For example, if you're in the top left of a 3x3 grid and want to jump to the bottom left you'd use 7<kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd>.

**Specific 3x3 grid answer**:

If you're always using a 3x3 layout you could try these mappings for the numpad, which always jump to the top left and then move the appropriate amount from there, with the key's position on the keypad jumping to the window's with 'equivalent' position on the screen:

```
noremap <k7> 1<c-w><c-w>
noremap <k8> 2<c-w><c-w>
noremap <k9> 3<c-w><c-w>
noremap <k4> 4<c-w><c-w>
noremap <k5> 5<c-w><c-w>
noremap <k6> 6<c-w><c-w>
noremap <k1> 7<c-w><c-w>
noremap <k2> 8<c-w><c-w>
noremap <k3> <c-w>b
```

*Edited: turns out c-w c-w goes to the top left at the start automatically. The explicit 1 is required in the first mapping, as c-w c-w without a count toggles between the current and the previously selected window.*

(The <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> mapping always goes to the top-left most window, the <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> mapping always goes to the bottom-rightmost).

Alternatively you could map each number to jump to the Nth window, so k6 would be 6 c-w c-w, rather than trying to lay out the keys as on screen.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer use standard vim keys(jkhl).

```
noremap <C-J> <C-W>w
noremap <C-K> <C-W>W
noremap <C-L> <C-W>l
noremap <C-H> <C-W>h
```

There is a trick if you notice that the first two maps can jump clock wise or the reverse, rather than just jumping up or down.

And you can also switch to any window directly with `<Number><C-J>`, for example, `2<C-J>` will go to the 2nd window.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but if you're using a terminal that supports it, you can set the following options:

```
:set mouse+=a
:set ttymouse=xterm2
```

and *click* on a buffer to switch to it. Yes, with the mouse.

A bunch of other mouse behavior works too - you can click to move the insertion point, drag to select text or resize splits, and use the scroll wheel.

Comment: I know this is heretical to Vim culture but this is really is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Ermmm... I'm pretty sure that this will not keep window layout as it is, but I use

```
:buf sys
```

to go to system.h,

```
:buf Sing
```

to go to `MyLargeNamedClassSingleton.cpp`

`buf` will do autocomplete (possibly menucompletion if so configured) so you can do

```
:buf part<Tab>
```

to list what files could match the `part` you typed. Beats the crap out of navigating buffers all around.

But I understand, this doesn't answer your specific question of course :)

Answer (score 1):

I like to move around with the arrow keys.
I map ctr+direction to move to the next window partition in that direction.

```
map <C-UP> <C-W><C-UP>
map <C-DOWN> <C-W><C-DOWN>
map <C-LEFT> <C-W><C-LEFT>
map <C-RIGHT> <C-W><C-RIGHT>
```

You cant jump directly from one window to another but I find that it makes it very easy to move between windows