# Is there a NERDTree or other project plugin for vim that integrates with git to show the status of files?

Tags: git, vim, nerdtree

I played with Aptana Studio for a while before moving over to VIM, and the only thing I really miss about Aptana Studio is the way that in their project view window your file names showed up a different color depending on their status in git (unchanged, changed but not staged, staged, untracked).  I know I can just go to terminal and find out, but having it right there in my editor without having to type any commands is really helpful.

Does anyone know if a plugin with this functionality exists for vim? Whether it is a plugin for NERDTree, a replacement, or something else?

Answer (score 11):

<s>For future reference, I created a fork of NERDTree that does exactly that, it can be found at https://github.com/SeySayux/NerdTreeGit .</s>

<s>Please note it's still in development, so it may break. It also contains a few oddities for which there aren't configurable options yet.</s>

UPDATE: The project linked above is discontinued. For a (much better) alternative, try this: https://github.com/Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin

Comment: Perfect in terms of feature/UI. But display is buggy when navigating as some redraws do not happen. Keep on the good job!

Comment: Is this gone for ever? Link is broken

Comment: @Hubro: Yes, I'm no longer maintaining that project. Updated the post with a better alternative.

Comment: The alternative is archived, without any news.

Answer (score 9):

Have you looked at [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)? It doesn't do exactly what you're looking for in terms of color-coding NERDTree based on git status -- I'm not aware of any Vim plugin that does, though it would be awesome. It does function as a pretty great little Git wrapper, and allows you to quickly view your project's status in a split window with `:Gstatus`. No need to go to the terminal.  You can even add a branch indicator for the current file to Vim's status line.

You can watch the first in a five-part screencast on fugitive.vim [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim---a-complement-to-command-line-git/).

Comment: +1 for the comment about adding the branch indicator, wasn't aware of this feature when using fugitive :)

Answer (score 4):

I use the [git.vim](https://github.com/amjith/git-vim) plugin that provides several git functionalities like add/commit/diff/log, etc. So from within vim, I've mapped `<Leader>gs` to `GitStatus`, which opens a new viewport and displays the status neatly:

[image]

But my favorite feature of this plugin is the `GitBranch()` function with which you can add the current branch to your status line, as I have [outlined in a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403716/shortcut-for-moving-between-vim-windows/6404246#6404246).

Along the same lines, it should be possible to write a function that calls `GitStatus` and greps the output and reports whether there are staged changes or unstaged changes present in the repo, which can then be conveniently added to the statusline.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you would like this https://github.com/Xuyuanp/git-nerdtree

It's my forked NERDTree.

Add git status support for NERDTree.You can indicate a file's git status, quickly see which files you have staged, unstaged and modified, or deleted in your project without any extra work.

### Indicator

- ✭ : Untracked
- ✹ : Modified in the working tree
- ✚ : Staged in the index (Exclude Renamed status)
- ➜ : Renamed
- ═ : Unmerged
- ✖ : Deleted (This indicator can't be shown, as NERDTree doesn't display deleted files. I have no prefect idea to solve this problem currently.)
- ✗ : Dirty (Only for directory)
- ✔︎ : Clean (Only for directory)

### Key mapping

As the same as [GitGutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) plugin default.

- `]c` : Jump to next indicator
- `[c` : Jump to prev indicator

Comment: Be carefull. It's still under development.