# Shortcut for switching back to last window in Vim?

Tags: vim

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> switches to the first window.

If currently I frequently edit in two of several windows, a shortcut for switching back to the last active window would be perfect.

Is there such a shortcut?

Comment: "last" window or "latest" window? Did you try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6404246/546861)?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

did you try

```
<c-w><c-p>
```

?

from help:

```
CTRL-W p                    *CTRL-W_p* *CTRL-W_CTRL-P*
CTRL-W CTRL-P   Go to previous (last accessed) window.

                        *CTRL-W_P* *E441*
CTRL-W P    Go to preview window.  When there is no preview window this is
        an error.
        {not available when compiled without the |+quickfix| feature}
```

Answer (score 9):

As Kent said
       `<c-w><c-p>` will go to previous

You can also navigate between windows using the directions h, j, k, and l

```
<c-w><c-h>
<c-w><c-j>
<c-w><c-k>
<c-w><c-l>
```

`<number><c-w><c-w>` will navigate to a specific window

Answer (score 5):

You can build your own short mapping; Vim is infinitely flexible in this regard. For example, many find these useful:

```
:noremap <C-j> <C-w>j
:noremap <C-k> <C-w>k
:noremap <C-h> <C-w>h
:noremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

Also, learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: I have those mappings too. it is so convenient. though it used `<ctrl>` I tried to mapp `<A-j/k> to something else` in terminal (urxvt), didn't make it....