# NavigateBackward in Vim?

Tags: vim

So `Ctrl-o` works *only* with jumps and has a history, `''` gets you back to your last position *regardless* of how you ended up there (jumping, navigating, etc) but there's no history for it.

What I'm looking for is the best of those two worlds, something like [Visual studio's NavigateBackward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324385/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-cursor-to-last-edit-position-in-visual-studio). `Ctrl-o` is good but a lot of the times it takes me back to positions I wouldn't expect, jumping is not the only way I navigate...

1. Is there a built-in command/way in vim that does this?
2. if not, is there a plugin for it?
3. if not, I have no problem writing a plugin myself, I know how to set/get the caret position, but I looked at the `autocmd-events` and couldn't find anything that fires when the
   caret changes position. How would I go about detecting the 'change' of the caret position?

Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want. Could you add an example/use case ? The question you linked is about jumping to the last edited position, which is `[count]g;` (also see `:changes`).

Comment: Thanks for `g;` didn't know about it. I'm not sure what's not clear, VS's navigate backwards takes you back to the last cursor position regardless of whether it's the last edited position, last navigated position, last jumped position, etc. I want to go back wherever I was, regardless of how I got there. None of the commands currently in vim takes me back where I was (with history) if I, for instance do `5j` or `10k` etc I either have to jump and use `Ctrl-o`, edit and use `g;` or `''` and accept it has no history. So basically what I'm asking for, is a version of `''` with history.

Comment: I don't think Vim supports it because each `h`, `j`, `k`, and `l` will have to push a position to the history stack.

Comment: `:he CursorMoved` might help?

Comment: Oh, I missed that, thanks! I'll see what I can cook with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to bluntly record all horizontal movement. At least I don't see much use for being able to undo word-wise movements and such. Your script is nice, but you might also like a more "specialized" solution..

```
" Make j and k leave jump marks when used with counts
function! JKMarks(motion)
    execute 'normal! ' . (v:count1 > 1 ? "m'" . v:count1 : '') . a:motion
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> j :<c-u>call JKMarks("j")<cr>
nnoremap <silent> k :<c-u>call JKMarks("k")<cr>

" Make mouse clicks leave jump marks
nnoremap <LeftMouse> m'<LeftMouse>
inoremap <LeftMouse> <c-o>m'<LeftMouse>
```

Comment: Couldn't agree with you more. I was just trying to get something 'working' - there's a lot to improve upon, including what you mentioned.

Comment: ooh, I just read about `m'` and it seems that it does something I initially thought of before writing my script, and that is appending to the jump list. This is actually much easier. Now I wonder how to make it travel through buffers...

Comment: Alright so I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768860/shortcut-for-switching-back-to-last-window-in-vim for navigating through windows, and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706958/vim-navigating-to-previous-and-next-buffers-in-edit-history for buffers. I think I'm good for now.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so thanks to @nodakai for `CursorMoved` I'm getting somewhere. It's not perfect yet - there's many areas to improve - it works only on one buffer and there's no forward navigation. Not bad for my first useful vimscript. Will improve

```
" Detect movement
augroup CursorChange
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorMoved * call OnCursorMoved()
augroup END

" Does the navigation
nnoremap <silent><leader>nb :call NavigateBackward()<cr>

let CursorPositions  = []
let PrevJump = []

function! OnCursorMoved()
    "echo "Cursor moved to: " . line('.') . ':' . col('.')
    "echo g:CursorPositions
    let l:current = [line('.'), col('.')]
    if (l:current != g:PrevJump) " to prevent getting stuck in a circle
        let g:CursorPositions = add(g:CursorPositions, l:current)
    endif
endf

function! NavigateBackward()
    let l:toIndex = len(g:CursorPositions) - 2  " get target jump position index
    if (l:toIndex < 0) | return | endif         " make sure it's within range
    let l:to = g:CursorPositions[l:toIndex]     " jump target
    let g:PrevJump = l:to                       " set previous to target
    call remove(g:CursorPositions, -1)          " remove last position
    call cursor(l:to[0], l:to[1])               " jump to target
endf

function! ResetCursorPositions() " for debugging
    let g:CursorPositions = [[line('.'), col('.')]]
endf
```